# Adjectival form of "collide"—"collideable" or "collidable"?

Tags: adjectives, orthography, suffixes, derivational-morphology, able-eable

I need to name an interface in a program I'm writing as being able to collide, but I've seen use of both *collideable* and *collidable* in projects with a similar type. Both of them look right in some ways, and wrong in others. Which spelling is more correct?

Comment: According to google: "collidable" About 46,300 results; "collideable" Did you mean: collidable? About 6,230 results. But this may just reflect the American English prevalence among programmers... :)

Comment: That's what I had figured, too. I'm glad I'm Canadian, I can pick and choose my spellings. >:D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Short answer: There's no clear choice; take your pick.

Long answer: Neither *collideable* nor *collidable* is a word you're likely to find in a dictionary, but in your context using it (one of them) may be exactly the right choice. As for the spelling preference, Wikipedia's detailed article on [American and British English spelling differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Dropped_e) says:

> Before *-able*, British English prefers *likeable*, *liveable*, *rateable*, *saleable*, *sizeable*, *unshakeable*, where American practice prefers to drop the *-e*; [borderline: *tradeable*, *smokeable*, *driveable*, *shareable*] but both British and American English prefer *breathable*, *curable*, *datable*, *lovable*, *movable*, *notable*, *provable*, *quotable*, *scalable*, *solvable*, *usable*, and those where the root is polysyllabic, like *believable* or *decidable*. Both forms of the language retain the silent *e* when it is necessary to preserve a soft *c*, *ch*, or *g*, such as in *traceable*, *cacheable*, *changeable*; both usually retain the "e"  after *-dge*, as in *knowledgeable*, *unbridgeable*, and *unabridgeable*. ("These rights are unabridgeable.")

The "polysyllabic" rule would point towards *collidable*, but [elsewhere](http://www.morewords.com/?%2aeable), a search brings up the following poly-syllabic words ending in *eable* (other than soft *c*, *ch*, *g* instances, of which there are many) (I haven't checked their provenance):

> canoeable diagnoseable disagreeable dislikeable fireable foreseeable handleable hireable machineable microwaveable removeable settleable throttleable unforeseeable unnameable upgradeable whistleable

Or you may want to look specifically at *-able* words formed from verbs ending in *-de*, and decide whether *-dable* or *-deable* is preferable:

> abradable codable decidable degradable dividable evadable excludable extrudable fadable gradable guidable hidable includable persuadable ridable/rideable slidable tradable/tradeable upgradable/upgradeable wadable/wadeable

It seems that analogy with *dividable* and *decidable* (the closest?) would suggest *collidable*. (But if you still prefer *collideable*, it's fine to use it…)

Comment: Nice answer. Of your second list, I would also remove the "-ee" words (such as "forseeable"), because removing an "e" there would also change the pronunciation. I'd also be tempted to remove the words that are compounds based on single-syllable "-eable" compounds (eg "dislikeable"), and also "fireable" since "fire" is a single syllable in most dialects. That tips the balance slightly further towards "collidable" :)

Answer (score 0):

*-able* forms adjectives that mean:

- able to be: *calculable*
- due to be: *payable*
- subject to: *taxable*
- relevant to, or in accordance to: *fashionable*
- having the quality to: *suitable*, *comfortable*

*Collidable* would mean *able to be collided*, not *able to collide*.
Instead of *collidable*,  you can use *hittable*, which would mean *able to be hit*.

As per choosing between *collidable* and *collideable*, the adjective that derives from *cite* is *citable*; in the same way, you should write *collidable*, not *collideable*.

Comment: "Able to be collided" is good enough for me; the interface is for objects that are handled by acollision detection system, and its siblings are interfaces named IDrawable and IUpdateable. (Yeah, with an E.)

Comment: _Collidable_, _collideable_, and hittable are not listed in the dictionary I have (the NOAD). The _Corpus of Contemporary English_ contains sentences using _hittable_; the word is found with a frequency of 0.10 per million.

Comment: _Collidable_, and _collideable_ are not found in the _Corpus of Contemporary American English_, nor in the _British National Corpus_.