# "Archivable" or "archiveable"

Tags: orthography, suffixes, programming, able-eable

I have an entity and I would like to describe it as being able to be archived.

Is it *archivable*, *archiveable*? The former seems OK for me, but I could find no wiktionary.org results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjective form of collide — collideable or collidable?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11646/) and [Creating words with -able suffix](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10440/)

Comment: @RegDwight I know the rule to create words like this but I know there are exceptions I could not find this word unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Archivable is correct.  *-e* more often than not drops off when adding *-able* (it varies a lot, mostly based on whether the word looks better with or without the *e*; I wouldn't say this is a case that greatly calls for keeping it, and the Google stats tend to indicate others agree).

Comment: Simply correct or are there any better? :)

Comment: @KARASZI István: If what you mean is that something can be archived, "archivable" is as good as it gets.

Comment: "Generally drops off" is a bold claim. Borrowing a leaf from ShreevatsaR: "tradeable, smokeable, driveable, shareable, canoeable, diagnoseable, disagreeable, dislikeable, fireable, foreseeable, handleable, hireable, machineable, microwaveable, removeable, settleable, throttleable, unforeseeable, unnameable, upgradeable, whistleable". And in British English: "likeable, liveable, rateable, saleable, sizeable, unshakeable".

Comment: @RegDwight: Well, I'd see that and raise you, but there are 69 words in a Debian `/usr/share/dict/words` that do appear to be formed by dropping -e and adding -able (excluding words formed by dropping *more* than a -e, like *abominable*), and the list is more than a hundred characters too long to post in a comment. I think you're right that "generally" is too much to say, though; it had been nagging at me too.

Comment: Interesting... especially as, at least I think so, that the -ing suffix on all those words would force the drop in the -e (like driving, trading, etc), with the exception of disagree (disagreeing). Would be interesting to know if there were a general rule for this.

Comment: @HorusKol: canoeing, disagreeing, foreseeing. I think a rule for "ing" is if the word ends in two vowels, you leave them both.

Answer (score 4):

It is *archivable*, in the same way from *cite* you get *citable*.

There are some differences between British English and American English. In British English, such adjectives (derived from a verb ending in *-e*) are preferred when they end with *-eable*; in American English, the preferred form ends in *-able* (the *-e* is removed from the verb).
The dictionary I have (the NOAD) doesn't report the word *archivable*, but it reports *citable* as derivative of *cite*, and *archival* as derivative of *archive*.

Answer (score 2):

The best reference point I can think of is "livable." I found this post because I had the same question about an interface I wanted to name "IArchivable." Looks to me like--regardless of how we got there, the consensus (on this side of the pond) is "archivable." So, that's what I'll be using!^)