# "Hirable" or "hireable"

Tags: adjectives, orthography, suffixes, able-eable

What is the correct adjective form of the word *hire*? I have seen references to both *hireable* and *hirable*.

I checked using Google's Ngram viewer book search and it appears that both have been in use since the 1800s with hirable becoming a bit more popular in the past decade or so:

[image: Google ngram hirable vs hireable]

Comment: Related: [“Collideable” or “collidable”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11646/adjective-form-of-collidecollideable-or-collidable), [“Archivable“ or “archiveable“](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11921/archivable-or-archiveable-or), and [Creating words with “-able” suffix](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10440/creating-words-with-able-suffix).

Comment: I think it's a pretty crappy word - it's one of those terribly marketing-ess buzzword-ish things. Don't use it.

Comment: How about using the word 'employable' instead - it's much more pleasing to the ear, and the eye!

Comment: Another alternative is `recruitable` without the vowel-ending conundrum

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the rule for attaching suffixes is as follows:

> If suffix begins with a vowel (a,e,i,o,u,y)
>   Root will attach directly to it
>   If suffix begins with a consonant
>   Root will need a combining vowel before attaching to the suffix

As in Example word: cardiogram
Breakdown of word: cardi/o/gram
Root = cardi
Combining vowel = o
Suffix = gram
Note: Suffix begins with a consonant
Combining vowel is needed

While Example word: cardialgia
Breakdown of word: cardi/algia
Root = cardi
Suffix = algia
Note: Suffix begins with a vowel
Combining vowel is not needed

However, there are words that do not follow this rule: i.e. "Friend-ship", "Govern-ment"

So I would redefine the rule a bit, as it isn't actually mine's.

If suffix begins with  a vowel , and the root word ends with  a vowel or consonant, the suffix attaches directly.

If however, the suffix begins with a consonant, and the root word ends with a vowel, it will need a combining vowel. *If however, the root word ends with  a consonant, the suffix will attach with no combining vowel.*

Which means your example would be written "hireable"

Comment: If you're going to quote a 'rule' leading you to define one of the alternatives as 'correct', you should quote the source thereof.

Comment: Compare this to a classic instance, `manageable`. Are some words plainly "exceptions?"

Answer (score 1):

This is starting to become a bit of a hoary old chestnut. Since OP has already established that both forms are and have been in widespread use for some time, what does it *mean* to ask "which is correct"?

In this particular case, although the NGram doesn't really make it clear, **hirable** really is becoming increasingly common. So by one standard, that's the spelling of the future, and is therefore arguably 'more correct'.

On the other hand, **hireable** was clearly the more prevalent form in the past - certainly in various linguistic subsets (in fact, it's *still* the preferred British usage, though that is changing even as I write). So arguably few people would seriously criticise anyone for using a more 'traditional' form.

In short, I think this question steers dangerously close to breaching FAQ guidelines which specify that questions should preferably admit of a single clear-cut answer which most competent speakers can agree on.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked and answered about 10 years ago, although no answer was at that time accepted and usage was arguably in flux.

Today, an updated Ngram shows that hirable was been the clear preference for the past 20 years, and has been preferred most of the time since the 1940s aside from a brief interlude.

I think we can confidently declare `hirable` to be the preferred spelling at this time and for the foreseeable future.

[image]

Comment: Google Scholar results for 'hirable' are also almost twice as frequent as for 'hireable'.

Comment: English having been devised other than in the US, does the fact that 'hireable' still outperforms 'hirable' in Google's 'BrE' corpus carry any weight?

Comment: The Ngram depiction above is for general Engish use, not American English in particular. The latest Ngram data for British English does not support your claim of continued preference for hireable over the period from 1940 to today. Instead, they are at roughly equal usage today after a brief recent period of 'hirable' dominance, and usage of 'hirable' is still down from historical norms. If I were an English publisher, I would conform to normal usage in an attempt to woo a global audience, but perhaps a niche work reflecting the tone of the 1860s would be designed otherwise.

Comment: [Google 1-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hirable%2Chireable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) show a dominance of the 8-letter variant in the 'BrE' corpus throughout most of the last 100 years; it is far from being 'the preferred spelling' in the UK. As OP asks about 'the correct [spelling]', this should be taken into account. Worldwide, _color_ doubtless outperforms _colour_, but this does not make _color_ '**the** correct spelling'.

Answer (score 0):

Languages evolve, Americans spell and pronounce words differently to British. To me hireable looks less likely to have the word mispronounced. Hireable without an e looks problematic as without the e after the first r the I sound has several options. Possibly a short I sound ?