# When to drop the 'e' when ending in -able?

Tags: orthography, suffixes, able-eable

I've seen a thread that generally asks about [Creating words with “-able” suffix](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10440/15661) But I don't think it answers my point, though they *are* admittedly dangerously close topics.

When do you drop the *'e'* when forming words suffixed with -*able*. My Spell checker likes *Unforgivable* but dislikes *Forgivable*. Dropping the '*e*' in the first case, and adding it in the second makes my spell checker happy. How do you determine when one is ok? Note that this is different from the linked [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10440/15661), where neither with or without the '*e*' is accepted.

<sub>(Having checked the OED it seems there is one accepted spelling of *Forgivable* but two of *Unforgiv(e)able*)</sub>

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/10456/11762)?

Comment: @Jim I did, but only really focuses on hyphenation. What do you want me to get from that answer that I've missed?

Comment: I expect your spellchecker doesn't like *forgivable* because - strange as it may seem - it's a pretty rare word compared to *unforgivable*. It's certainly not a matter of spelling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's why I referenced the OED as well.

Comment: Yes, I didn't suppose there was any real debate on whether *forgivable* was a valid word, or how it's spelt. Just trying to guess why your spellchecker didn't recognise it. I can't explain why it liked the "e" version though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: While, humph, if "forgivable" is a "pretty rare word" to you compared to "unforgivable", I guess that just says something about the kind of person you are. :-)

Comment: @Jay: Obviously I'm a competent native speaker, so *unforgivable* certainly isn't going to cause me any problems. But it's outweighed 5:1 by *unforgivable* in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unforgivable%2Cforgivable&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which is fairly unusual for *word* vs *unword*. I was just trying to guess at a possible reason for the spellchecker's behaviour, is all.

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11646/adjective-form-of-collidecollideable-or-collidable/11654#11654)?

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 no I hadn't seen that. It looks like a perfectly good answer. I've submitted a close request (exact duplicate). I'm note sure if it could be merged.

Comment: @Pureferret I thought the consecutive vowels running together was relevant. Having "ea" might confuse some people to the pronounciation (I wouldn't expect this to actually happen, unless the reader had never seen the word "forgive" before), so it might be correct to use a hyphen.

Comment: @Jim Ahh I see! But it doesn't change the difference between *Unforgivable* and *Forgiveable*

Comment: @Pureferret No, it doesn't, but that difference exists in your spellchecker, which isn't necessarily the correct way to write it. It's just what that particular spell-checker thinks is right (which in this case is inconsistent).

Comment: My spellchecker accepts _forgivable_, but doesn't accept _forgiveable_, which is marked in red. I am using the American English spellchecker.

Comment: How do you know it’s *-able* and not *-ible*? The OED attests more than 400 *-ible* words.  And no, I’m not counting *Bible* and such. *force > forcible, fuse > fusible, immerse > immersible, reduce > reducible*.  There are lots and lots of those.

Comment: @tchrist I don't really understand what you mean

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only situation that comes to mind where an *-e-* is *absolutely* required before *-able* is when it modifies the pronunciation of a consonant, typically *g* or *c*:

> *Manageable* (*g* as in *giant*) versus
>   **managable* (*g* as in *gut*)
>
> *Traceable* (*c* as in *once*) versus
>   **tracable* (*c* as in *cut*)

Of course, that problem would exist in reverse for *-ible* words, but in practice it doesn’t arise as these are less common than their *-able* cousins.

The *-e-* also serves to make a vowel long where otherwise it could be interpreted as short. *Scrapeable* definitely begins with *scrape*, *scrappable* definitely begins with *scrap*, but *scrapable* could go either way; and if the common misspellings of short-vowelled words ending in *-able* are any evidence, it is likely to be read as *scrappable*.

In addition, when adding *-able* to words that end with a [syllabic consonant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant), the *-e-* tends to be retained, to stress that the consonant still comprises its own syllable. [tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist) offers:

> *Throttleable*, *(un)settleable*, *(un)whistleable*, *(un)riddleable*

To my mind, *whistlable* is three syllables—[wɪs.lə.bɫ]—whereas *whistleable* is four: [wɪs.l.ə.bɫ]. That says nothing about which one I’d choose, because my pronunciation varies freely between them. Although, I do think that a two-syllable pronunciation of “settlers” (thus a three-syllable “settlable”) sounds rather Southern or Southwestern.

Comment: + scrapeable/scrappable is a good example. It's a shame we don't use a verb "to cape" (*form into a cape, perhaps)*. There was discussion over whether the Deepwater Horizon leak could be capped *("cappable")*, so given we've already got the totally unrelated word *capable*, that would really set the cat among the pigeons!

Comment: Ah, interesting point. Let me clarify for you that there is a general rule that when "g" or "c" is followed by "e", "i" or "y" it has the soft sound (g->j, c->s), but when followed by any other letter it has the hard sound (c like k, g like ... g).

Comment: dictionary.com gives "scrapable" as the correct spelling for a word meaning "able to be scraped". I couldn't find any listing for "scrappable", though one would think that this would be a perfectly good word meaning "suitable for turning into scrap", as in, "Once we remove the motor the wire should be scrappable."

Comment: @Jay: The fact that any particular inflected form isn't explicitly given by any particular (or indeed *every*) dictionary doesn't necessarily mean it's not a "valid word". In the case of *scrappable* [here are hundreds of written instances](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=scrappable&pbx=1&oq=scrappable&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4470l7058l3l7396l10l10l0l0l0l0l228l1752l1.5.4l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=5cc1ae9b34eaacd8&biw=1578&bih=836). And it'll be far more common in things written later than the stuff indexed in Google Books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I meant that I couldn't find "scrappable" in any of the several dictionaries I checked, not just that one I mentioned where I found "scrapable". Quite true that the failure of a word to appear in any particular dictionary does not prove that it "isn't a real word", but it would be an indication that it is unusual or specialized. What I was trying to say was that that surprised me. It seemed like it should be a fairly common word.

Comment: @Jay: A decade ago I'd have considered *scrappable* to be on a par with *scrappage*. They were both quite uncommon words, and even today Google makes me confirm I really want *scrappable* (20k hits) rather than *scrapable* (itself only 350K hits). But *scrappage* is right up there with over 4M hits, on account of all the government incentives to persuade us to scrap old energy-inefficient technology. Which will obviously lead a *lot* of people to wonder *"Is my old gas-guzzler car scrappable?"* (i.e. - *"Will the government give me a lot of money for 'doing the right thing'?"*).

Comment: The OED attests: *throttleable, settleable & unsettleable, haveable, giveable, whistleable, unriddleable,* &c.  What model explains those sorts, hm?

Comment: @tchrist: In *throttleable*, *(un)settleable*, *whistleable*, and *(un)riddleable*, the E is there because of the syllabic L; I’ll edit to add. I’ve never seen *haveable* or *giveable*, but they’re cromulent as there’s really no universal rule.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I personally find *liveable* and *livable* equally acceptable, though I'd actually write the *livable* myself (NGram says *liveable* was the more common until 100 years ago). On the other hand, if I read (or needed to write) *haveable/giveable* I'd expect the "e" because they're at the very least "unusual" forms, so it's good to have that extra letter to make it obvious where they're coming from.

Comment: ...but let's not forget that at this level it's pointless to pontificate about "correct" spelling.

Comment: The OED gives only *whistleable*, and gives /ˈhwɪs(ə)ləb(ə)l/ for the pronunciation in a broad phonemic transcription. As for ‘correctness’, I’m pretty sure around here all anybody really cares about is whether they’ve won the popularity contest at the top of the ngram hit-parade, just so they can go nyah-nyah.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: To a first approximation I have no interest at all in the concept of "correct" in things like spelling. What matters most is what people actually say/write. I don't reference ngrams in order to "win" - I reference it to show actual usage, historical trends, US/UK differences, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you’re @-replying the wrong person. I’m a descriptivist as well, and the only notion of “incorrect” spelling I mention is referring to nonstandard, minority use of nondoubled consonants around short vowels.

Comment: Ooops, sorry! Must have been a "senior moment" brought on by conflating the fact that you're the originator here so you don't need mailboxing, whereas @tchrist (who I mean to notify) seemed to be replying to *me* without mailboxing. I'm completely with you on this issue, obviously.

Comment: I just had to check when writing the word "shareable." The rules would seem to say drop the e, but that's incorrect. I tried to think of other words ending in "re," and only came up with flare, which also ends up as "flareable." Not sure if that's always true.

Comment: As for the words ending with "c" or "g", it would be really nice to use *-ible* suffix instead (thus *tracible* and *managible* - the same pronunciation!), but unfortunately it isn't productive anymore (i.e. us(e)able only with some Latin-origin words).

Answer (score 8):

When I was in elementary school I was taught that the rule was: If a word ends with a silent "e" that serves to make the previous vowel long, and you add a suffix that begins with a vowel, drop the "e". If the suffix begins with a consonant, do not drop the "e".

Thus: forgive + able = forgivable

But: forgive + ness = forgiveness

Here's an Internet source that states this rule like this, "Another thing to keep in mind is that when a suffix is added that begins with a vowel and the main words ends with a silent "e", that silent "e" should be dropped like it is in the words pricing and surprising. However, if the suffix used begins with a consonant, the silent "e" should be kept such as in the words likeness and advancement." [http://www.thefreelibrary.com/English+Spelling+Rules+Adding+Prefixes+and+Suffixes-a01073900597]

thefreedictionary.com gives the spellings as "forgivable" and "unforgivable" -- no "e" in either word.

But frankly I often see spellings that do not follow this rule. Whether this is because people are not following a consistent rule or the rule as I was taught was a simplification and there are other cases, I can't say.

By the way, another general rule I learned is that when adding a suffix that begins with a vowel, if the base word ends with a short vowel followed by a single consonant, double the consonsant. If the vowel is long or there is more than one consonant, don't double the consonant.

For example, big + er = bigger. But cool + er = cooler (the vowel sound is long) and bank + er = banker (two consonants). (Ooh, I just noticed that I am using the suffix -er with two different meanings: "bigger" means "more big", but "banker" does not mean "more bank". In "cooler" it can have either meaning: more cool, as in "Today is coooler than yesterday", or a thing that cools, as in, "Put the soft drinks in the cooler.")

Comment: Yes, there are other cases.  The OED attests quite a few that fit no simple model. See my other comment.

Comment: But the 'e' doesn't make the vowel long in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely, there is no single rule or even a set of rules that can be applied consistently and algorithmically in all cases.

At least the set (un)forgiv(e)able seems to have started the process of shedding the ***e*** c1880. I do not yet know for sure what happened around 1880, though.

nGram *forgivable | forgiveable | unforgivable | unforgiveable* 1800-2000
[image]

What is surprising to note, however, is that the ***e*** does still survive, apparently fighting back.

nGram *forgiveable | unforgiveable* **1960-2000**
[image]