# “Fadable” vs. “Fadeable”: which is preferred?

Tags: suffixes, able-eable

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55194) has some great insight on adding -*able* to the word "scrape". I'm wondering if there is any reason to use "fadable". "Fadeable" has a very clear pronunciation and is how I would guess it should be written because the *e* makes the *a* long. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm very interested in this because some words I just know drop the "e", as in "use" -> "usable", while other words look weird to me, for some reason, if the "e" is dropped. Words ending in "-ce" and "-ge" generally keep the "e" to maintain the soft "c" and "g"--but then we have the alternative spelling "knowledgable" for "knowledgeable" (which goes along with "judgment" and "judgement").

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.