# Pipelineable/pipelinable?

Tags: adjectives, orthography, able-eable

In computer science, [pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing)) is a common technique used to increase the throughput of processing units, both in the context of hardware and software.
When describing a context that are amenable to pipelining, we would say that is is *pipelinable/pipelineable*.

I have found neither *pipelinable* nor *pipelineable* in any dictionary, so I assume this form (along with *pipelining*?) has been invented by researchers/engineers. When I search Google scholar, I find 659 results for [pipelinable](https://scholar.google.ch/scholar?hl=en&q=pipelinable), and 1550 results for [pipelineable](https://scholar.google.ch/scholar?hl=en&q=pipelineable), leading me to believe that there is also no clear consensus in the scientific community.

Are there any arguments for using one over the other when it's not a dictionary word, or is it truly arbitrary?

Comment: The ***pipe*** prefix makes no difference. M-W has [this entry:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lineable) *Definition of **lineable** - variant spelling of LINABLE*.

Comment: See also [Adjective form of “collide”—“collideable” or “collidable”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11646/adjective-form-of-collide-collideable-or-collidable)

Comment: @FumbleFingers This seems to perfectly answer my question - I'd accept it if you post this as an answer (essentially either spelling is accepted)

Comment: jlicht - you can uptick my comment if you like. But I voted to close as a duplicate of the earlier question, and you could have searched for that M-W entry yourself anyway.